# How do I format the MATLAB code in PyCharm?

Tags: matlab, pycharm

It is well known that MATLAB code is widely used. However, up to now there is no handy tool for formatting MATLAB code. So, how do I implement this function in Pycharm?

Comment: There is a MATLAB plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10941-matlab-support

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you should download a Matlab formatter. (https://github.com/affenwiesel/matlab-formatter-vscode/blob/master/formatter/matlab_formatter.py)
2. We need to slightly change that file because the overwriting function is not available in the current version. We can add the following code at the end of the "formatFile" function:

```py
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            for line in wlines:
                f.write(line+'\n')
```

3. Finally, we can create an external tool in Pycharm to implement this function.
   [image]
4. After that, when we want to format a specific file, we just need to invoke this external tool.
   [image]